# Android: How to: validate Location's latitude and longitude values

Tags: android

How do you validate Location? seems that setting it to these values Location.setLatitude(999) & Location.setLongitude(999) are valid (means there's no any validation). Is there a Android way to validate it? (i know the maximum and minimum values of it but just wondering if there's already available using Android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in Android to do this.  Like you said, it's probably best to just define the min and max.

On a side note, you could call Google's Geocoding service and pass in your lat and long as input parameters to check the result for a valid location before calling Location.setLatitude():
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: >check the result for a valid location before calling Location.setLatitude() -> can't understand this phrase, would you elaborate it more? How can I check the result?

Comment: I was thinking you could call the service and get a JSON or XML result. Here's an example of a JSON response; you could check for the "OK" status and allow or deny the parameters based on this return code: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

Comment: Got it. but i opt to create my own simple validation by defining min and max because I am not using google's api.

Answer (score 18):

Here is the simple function that validates latitude and longitude

```
public boolean isValidLatLng(double lat, double lng){
    if(lat < -90 || lat > 90)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(lng < -180 || lng > 180)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Latitude measures how far north or south of the equator a place is located. The equator is situated at 0°, the North Pole at 90° north (or 90°, because a positive latitude implies north), and the South Pole at 90° south (or –90°). Latitude measurements range from 0° to (+/–)90°.

Longitude measures how far east or west of the prime meridian a place is located. The prime meridian runs through Greenwich, England. Longitude measurements range from 0° to (+/–)180°.

Reference taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A Kotlin solution that I made on the playground can be found [here](https://pl.kotl.in/sGhCsSXfs). Logic is from another [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7780993/7900721)

```kotlin
data class LatLng(val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double) {
    val isValid: Boolean by lazy {
        latitude >= -90 && latitude <= 90
                && longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180
    }
}
```